# Javascript minification why is false replaced with !1 and true with !0

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

I'm writing an app using Enyo2 which comes with a minification tool based on UglifyJS. 
I've noticed that:

```
var t = false
```

is replaced with

```
var t=!1
```

The same way true is replaced with !0. I'm sure there is a good explanation for that, I just can't find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is one apparently. If you use 1 or 0 to translate true or false, it would be shorter but seen as integers. If you add ! in front and reverse them, it will be coalesced into booleans and still be short.

Answer (score 19):

It is the smallest non-ambiguous way to express the value.

`true` uses 4 characters on the wire and `false` uses 5 characters.  `!1` &  `!0` use  2 characters.

Comment: So why not simply use 1 as true and 0 as false?

Comment: Because 1 &  0 could be number values too.   That's why I added  non-ambiguous

Comment: @ArekS 1 and 0 aren't booleans; they're numbers. Comparisons could potentially be messed up

Comment: @Jason it would be nice if you could add that comment to the answer ;-)

Comment: why dont we simply use `const T = !0, F= !1` during minification, and use `T` and `F` everywhere instead of !0 and !1. that's gonna save even more space.

Comment: @sanjeev I think it's because most short variable names like that would already be taken for other things and since you'd be saving at most one character per boolean literal it's probably not worth it. There are better cases to use the one letter variable names

Answer (score 11):

In JavaScript, 0 is a [*falsy* value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). This means that `0` equates to `false` when represented as a boolean type. 1 on the other hand; or any other positive number for that matter, is not a falsy value and will equate to `true`.

Here we could just set:

```
t = 0; // false
t = 1; // true
```

The problem with this is that these values are integers (numbers) and not boolean values (*true* or *false*). Using a strict equality check (`===`) we'd find:

```
t = 0;
t == false; // true
t === false; // false
```

[The `!` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) performs a logical NOT operation on the value, and can be used as a quick way to convert any value to boolean:

```
t = !1;
t == false; // true
t === false; // true
```

Performance-wise, there is [not really much difference](http://jsperf.com/logical-not-vs-compare-to-false/2) between `if (!t)` and `if (t == true)`, however in minification terms this reduces our JavaScript by 7 bytes, allowing it to be downloaded ever so slightly quicker.

Comment: nice answer. but what about performances ? is it more performant to write !0 or false ?

Answer (score 3):

Negation converts a non-boolean, but truthy value to a pure boolean.

I ran this in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
> !1
false
> !0
true
```

Therefore, `!1` is interchangeable with `false` and `!0` is interchangeable with `true`.  So now that we know it's safe to change it, the next question is why.  Well, because it's fewer bytes.  The point of minification is to make the code smaller, but compatible.

Long-story short, it's a safe way to compress the literal `true` and `false` so they take less space when transmitting over the wire.